# Ngrx/effects: get error TS2345: Argument of type 'Product[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Product'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

When compiling, I get the following error (although there are no errors in the browser console, and the application works correctly).

```
ERROR in src/app/services/product.service.ts(15,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Product>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product[]>'.
  Type 'Product' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
src/app/store/effects/product.effect.ts(22,76): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Product[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Product'.
  Type 'Product[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': id, name, description
src/app/store/effects/product.effect.ts(23,44): error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/store/reducers/index.ts(9,5): error TS2322: Type '(state: State, action: Action) => State | { loading: boolean; loaded: boolean; products: Product; }'
is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<State, Action>'.
  Type 'State | { loading: boolean; loaded: boolean; products: Product; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.
    Type '{ loading: boolean; loaded: boolean; products: Product; }' is not assignable to type 'State'.
      Types of property 'products' are incompatible.
        Type 'Product' is missing the following properties from type 'Product[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

**product.model.ts**

```
export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

**product.effect**

```
import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { map, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as productActions from '../actions';
import * as fromServices from '../../services';

@Injectable()
export class ProductEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private productService: fromServices.ProductService
    ) {}

    @Effect()
    loadProducts$ = this.actions$.pipe(ofType(productActions.LOAD_PRODUCTS),
        switchMap(() => {
            return this.productService
                .getProducts()
                .pipe(
                    map(products => new productActions.LoadProductsSuccess(products)),
                    catchError(error => of(new productActions.LoadProductsFail(error)))
                );
        })
    );
}
```

Screenshot of state

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUF96.png)

Comment: `ERROR in src/app/services/product.service.ts(15,9)` its clear the problem originates from `product.service.ts`. Can you show us code for that? Its definitely a ts thing, you need to define that param you pass in as being `any` data type

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xfmpsu0/

Comment: update your question with the code so we can actually read it, dont paste it in comments.

Comment: Sorry, i update it

Comment: You didn't update your *question* you put it in comments again. Update your *question* with the relevant code.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/7xfmpsu0

Comment: Dude.... update the **question** with the code, you keep dropping links to jsfiddle in **comments**. You need to put it in the actual **question**. Update your **question** to show us the relevant code... which is `product.service.ts`

Comment: When i paste code i get error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", so then i upload them on fiddle, dude...

Comment: thats fine, but at least paste the link in the *question* and **not** the comments for future reference. Anyway, check my answer for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `getProducts()` to return an observable of type `Product[]` but instead you are trying to return an observable of type `Product`. Change `getProducts()` to return an observable of type `any`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { Product } from '../models';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ProductService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getProducts(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(`/assets/products.json`)
            .pipe(catchError((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json())));
    }

}
```